# Ganpati Pujan in Ramacharitamanas during Shiv-Parvati Vivah

Tags: shiva, ganesha, parvati, ramcharitmanas

There is a doha in Ramacharitmanas in Baal Kaand during Shiv-Parvati Vivah

> मुनि अनुसासन गणपतिही, पूजेऊ सम्भू-भावनि|
> कोउ सुनि संसाय करई जनि, सुर अनादि जिय जानि||

But Ganpati was the son of Shiv and Parvati, during their marriage he was not born so how come they are worshipping him? I haven't understood this doha properly due to my poor knowledge of awadhi language.

Comment: Yeah it does, thanks for this.

Comment: Okay :) then you can mark the button which the site displays to you.

Comment: Namaste welcome to HSE. While on the site, you can go through the [help centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as well as [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). The rules insist on deriving the answer based on scriptures or great acharyas. Hope you have a good time on the site :)